# Logging practices with multiple web applications

Tags: logging, jmx, logback

We need to host multiple web applications in a clustered glassfish environment. Logback is the logging framework used by the web applications. Modification of the logging configuration (for e.g. the log levels) is a question for which I would like to get some expert opinions and suggestions.

Currently we have placed the logback configuration files into individual war files for couple of reasons

1. Manually placing the logback.xml outside the war file adds an additional task to the installer/upgrader.
2. Any modifications done to the configruation file in the future versions of the web-application would have to be taken care by the software-upgrader. Any e.g. of such a modification could be to accept the log file location as a JNDI property. Number of web-applications adds complexity to this task.

The disadvantage of placing the configuration file in the war is that it makes it hard to do any modifications. For e.g. adding new loggers or changing the log level.
JMX is an alternative supported by logback but I see two issue with it

1. Any changes made through JMX cannot be persisted. Any server restarts would lose the configured changes.
2. JMX support provided by logback does not allow to add new appenders for e.g. a new file appender

I would appreciate if you could provide any suggestions about the placement of the logback configuration files or the JMX issues I mention above.

Answer (score 0):

We've faced similar issues and had to solve with other logging mechanisms- it can indeed be a pain with unpleasant tradeoffs.  I'm just starting to use LogBack, but my understanding is that it allows for variable substitution in the config file (http://logback.qos.ch/manual/joran.html#variableSubstitution).  My plan is to use this capability to route logs as needed using system properties as shown in the linked example.

As for JMX, agreed.  We use JMX extensively for monitoring and for making temporary changes to internal configuration when conditions warrant, but JMX is not a great choice for making permanent changes; at the very least those should go through a change control process.

My recommendation: explore the variable substitution approach and use JMX for temporary runtime adjustments.

Comment: Actually the two problems I mention above cannot be solved through variable substitution. Losing the changes made through JMX like changing the log level of a logger cannot be solved using variable substition nor the second issue about adding new appenders